# I have a bed mark

Tags: grammar

He just awake.

He looked at his hand and said,

> "I have a bed mark."

[image]

What do we call for this?

The mark was caused by the wrinkles bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no clue and I'm a native speaker.  I have always just described them as you called them: "bed marks" or "bed wrinkles" or I've described them as "wrinkles on my skin from sleeping".  I don't know what they're called and I've tried finding the word.  I hope someone will have a better answer than I do.

Comment: They're sometimes called **sleep lines** or **sleep wrinkles** or **skin creases**.

Comment: Can I say, "I have a wrinkle on my hand."

Comment: Yeah, but you should describe how the wrinkle came to be, so I would say, "I have a wrinkle on my hand from sleeping on it." That's one possible way of many to say it.

Answer (score 0):

The general term for this seems to be "skin indentation".